# How can I do in Woocommerce to apply discounts only for logged users?

Tags: woocommerce

I´m looking for a hook that can help me apply discounts only in case that user is logged. Every one can see the discount but it is applyed only for registered users.

Comment: Shure, but how to recalculate the order total after knowig that user is logged/not logged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the conditional tag `is_user_logged_in()` in an `IF` statement **inside any function** that you can pick in [any of those related threads](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwoocommerce%5D+discounts), to restrict it only for logged users.

If you choose the right working code, it will recalculate the totals by itself for logged in users *(just as well as if it was without restrictions)*.

Answer (score -1):

Solved.
Sharing my solution:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'no_discount_if_not_logged_in', 10, 1);
function no_discount_if_not_logged_in( $cart ) {

    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {              

        foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {        

            $descount_eliminate = $cart_item['data']->get_regular_price();

            $cart_item['data']->set_price($descount_eliminate );

        }
    }

}
```